# how to receive data from mqtt and open cv video stream at the same time

Tags: loops, opencv, interface, mqtt

My project need to receive mqtt data and videostream data at the same time. However, when my raspi receiving video data by open cv, it cant receive iOT data at the same time.

My raspi need to check if the iot data is on, and the video will not turn on and receive data.
So the piority is
iOT sensor check if there is something detected-----> video will not turn. (case 1)
iOT sensor check if there is nothing detected-------> video turn on and receive another image data.

[Update 2]

```
# import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils
import time
import serial
import struct
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

#subscribe mqtt publisher with topic "esp/pot"
def on_connect(client, userdata,flags, rc):
    client.subscribe("/esp/pot")

#get the data from the publisher and save to integer variable "bdy"    
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    bdy=int(msg.payload)

#when disconnect stop the loop of mqtt function    
def on_disconnect(client, userdata,rc=0):
    client.loop_stop()

#Assign the mqtt client as client    
client = mqtt.Client()
#Assign the mqtt connect function to client connect
client.on_connect = on_connect
#Assign the mqtt message function to client message
client.on_message = on_message

#set the client connect to local broker host
client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60) # localhost is the Raspberry Pi itself

#Below is setting up the OpenCV function
# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#get the video if path provided
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
    help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=0,
    help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# define detect object, in here is a green object
# define the lower and upper boundaries of the "green" color in HSV value
# ball in the HSV colorspace, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
greenLower = (25, 96, 49)
greenUpper = (39, 255, 255)
Lower = greenLower
Upper = greenUpper

#define the trace point of the object detected, here is centroid
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])

#setup the serial port for arduino, which is for another motor control
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
            

# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam (we use webcam in this project
if not args.get("video", False):
    vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

# allow the camera or video file to warm up
time.sleep(2.0)
#initialize the integer variable "bdy" to zero
bdy = 0


# main function body, keep looping
while True:
    # grab the current frame of the webcam
    frame = vs.read()

    # handle the frame from VideoCapture or VideoStream
    frame = frame[1] if args.get("video", False) else frame

    # if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a frame,
    # then we have reached the end of the video
    if frame is None:
        break

    # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
    # color space
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=246)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # construct a mask for the color "green", then perform
    # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
    # blobs left in the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, Lower, Upper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

    # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
    # (x, y) center of the green object
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    #initial center value
    center = None
    
    #start mqtt client loop function for receiving data from broker, int variable "bdy"
    client.loop_start()
   #if the data from broker is not 1
    if bdy != 1:
        #printout bdy value for debug
        print (bdy)
    # only proceed if at least one contour of green object was found
        if len(cnts) > 0:
        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid
            c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
            #save webcam detected object centroid to cX and cY
            ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
            #locate the centre of the green object
            center = (cX, cY)
        # only proceed if the radius of the detected green object meets a minimum size, 
        # say radius >2 to remove unneccssary noise
            if radius > 2:
            # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
            # then update the list of tracked points
            #cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                #(0, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    
                # print x_position
                print (cX)
                # send the cX value to the arduino by serial port with braud rate 9600
                ser.write(struct.pack('>H', cX))
       # if the data from broker is not 1, 
       # here the broker actually just send data from sensor with digital value
       # so it should be 0
        else:
            print("boundary detected")
    
    #stop the client loop function from receive data for clearing the retain messsage
    client.loop_stop()
    # show the frame from webcam to raspberry pi screen for debug
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    #awaiting user press key for action
    chkKey = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the main function body "while True loop"
    if chkKey == ord("q"):
         break
    
# if we are not using a video file, stop the camera video stream
if not args.get("video", False):
    vs.stop()

# otherwise, release the camera
else:
    vs.release()

# close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#stop the client loop function
client.loop_stop()
```

Comment: How have you already tried to combine those 2 separate sections of code?

Comment: Hi hardillb, I have added my combine code to the OP, i keep receive the mqtt data.. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to clearly explain what happens when you run that combined code and how this differs from what you want.

Comment: Hey hardillb, thank you for your prompt reply. I have updated my code with expanation. What i received with excute the updated code is the printout keep printing 0 and the location of the green object. And the broker data cannot successfully pass to the raspi.  I guess this is because the function keep suck at the bdy != 0 condition. I dont know why :(

Comment: Just adding more code doesn't answer the question "clearly explain what happens..."

Comment: my problem is the variable "bdy" cannot clearly send from publisher to raspi. if the mqtt program seperately execute, which work perfectly.

Comment: I guess the client.loop_start() doesnt get the correct varibable "bdy" value, i dont know why

Comment: I found a problem. when i try to use loop_start() function, i received there is a delay on the message displayed on the printout. How can i get the most update data? It is ok when some data loss, what i need is fast response from the printout message

Comment: In case someone want to know it, i add delay 100ms on the esp01 server side, it solved the problem. I guess its because the braud rate of the sensor sending data is too fast (esp01 115200)